# How can I make a simulation to show that false dichotomies make for bad statistics?

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, genetics

I'm trying to make a point for a paper that, given that ADHD symptoms/autism exist on a spectrum, to studying the genetics of ADHD by grouping people into either affected or not affected reduces statistical power. I also want to know roughly how much power is lost by doing it.

I tried to do this by simulating the height of 1000 people using 100 binary factors of normally distributed effect size and grouping people into either tall or not tall and using logistic regression, and comparing that to using t-tests with the absolute value for height. I could do this for just one person using

```
mean.height=170
subject.1.factors=sample(c(1,0), 100, replace=T)

a=rnorm(100)
factors=a-mean(a)
subject.1.factors= sample(c(1,0),100, replace=T)
subject.1.height= sum(subject.1.factors*factors+1)*mean.height/100
```

but I couldn't find a way to do this for 1000 people and store the data in a useful way. Is there a way I can do this efficiently? Is there a better way than this to achieve my goal?

thanks for taking the time to read my question!

edit: I believe the output I am looking for is a table with a row for each subject, one column for height, and additional columns for the 1/0 status of each of the 100 factors.

Comment: Variables `subject.1.genetics` and `genes` are not defined. Please use reproducible examples.

Comment: Changing now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need?

```
mean.height=170

subjects=c()
factors.subj=c()
subject.factors=sample(c(1,0),100, replace=T)
for(i in 1:1000){
  a=rnorm(100)
  factors=a-mean(a)
  subjects[i]= sum(subject.factors*factors+1)*mean.height/100
}
df=cbind(subjects,subject.factors)
hist(subjects);head(df)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Not quite.this is useful in that it creates a height distribution and displays it nicely, however, it loses all the information on the factors associated with each height. I believe the output I am looking for is a table with a row for each subject, one column for height, and additional columns for the 1/0 status of each of the 100 factors.

Comment: I fix it with your suggestion, Cabbage.

Comment: Hi Ricardo. That does a create a table with subject height and subject factors, but it just lists the factors of a single subject and lines that up with the height of all subjects.

I'm looking for each subjects factors to be given in a series of collumns to the right of their height. 

So something resembling column names like this

Subject.Number/Subject.Height/Factor1/Factor2/Factor3/Factor4/....

Comment: Help is no longer needed. Thank you all for your contributions!

Answer (score 0):

> x=rnorm(100)
>
> ## producing my normally distributed effect sizes
>
> factors=sample(c(0,1), 1000*100, replace=T)
>
> ## creating a list of ones and zeros at random
>
> factor.coeffs= x-mean(x)
>
> ## making the mean of my effect sizes 0 (not necessary step)
>
> mean.height=175
>
> ## represents height in cms
>
> factors.matrix=matrix(factors, nrow=1000, ncol=100, byrow=T)
>
> ## creating a 100 (one for each factor) by 1000 (one for each person) matrix
>
> impacts.matrix=(sweep(factors.matrix, MARGIN=2, factor.coeffs, '*'))
>
> ## changing the 1s and 0s into their effects on the persons height
>
> subject.heights=mean.height-rowSums(impacts.matrix)
>
> ## making a vector of all my subjects heights
>
> hist(subject.heights)
>
> ## visualising to make sure the data makes sense.
>
> analysis.matrix=cbind(subject.heights,factors.matrix)
>
> ## combines into a single matrix I can run statistical tests on

^ I have got the data into the structure I needed by using the code above. I'll update this answer once I've finished the analysis. Sorry for formatting.